# Can't change moment locale

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using moment.js and I can't change the default locale :

```
moment.locale('fr');
console.log(moment.locale()); // en
```

Comment: Did you include the moment `fr` locales in your index ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5ktr4u19/1/ - looks fine -- need to include the `locale/fr.js` file

Comment: it works, thx .... I feel stupid

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It look like you want to use a locale which is not register in your moment instance.
To check for that run in a browser console :

```
moment.locales()
```

It will return a array with all the locales that are currently registered.
If you don't see 'fr', it meens you should either include locale/fr.js or use [moment-with-locales.js](http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js)